# How to change clocks position in Android 6.0

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, settings, lock-screens, clock

I have a quite simple problem: my screen is partially broken so I don't see clocks in it's default position, it looks like `13.XX` and I don't see XX because screen is just black there.

So I want to change clocks position to be bottom-docked. I recall I did it in android 2.X several years ago, but I wasn't able to find this option in Android 6.0. It only allows me to change clock type, but doesn't have any options to change its position on the lock screen.

Is there any solutions for this?

Comment: press and hold on digital clock's(hour's position) visible portion and drag it to bottom. have you checked that?

Comment: It just unlocks the phone

Comment: Just for clarification: Are you speaking about the time displayed in the notification bar – or about a widget on your home screen? Guess Rahul assumed the latter but you mean the former. Or something altogether.

Comment: Yes @Izzy, my comment is for clock widget at home screen. And, yes he asked for lock screen clock. I think, it required to install some third party app/root to edit lock screen elements. Alex, please mention your device name on your question.

Comment: @RahulGopi I doubt that. Because, it cannot "unlock the phone" as it already must have been unlocked to press-and-hold that. And to confirm, from the question text: "position on the lock screen" means "lock screen", not "home screen".

Comment: Well, if you're phone comes with an AOSP(stock android) rom, you probably wont be able to change your clock position. And android 6.0 doesn't allow that. You need to root your phone in order to change your clock position. Or you can install a custom rom in your device. And of course, rooting your phone will void your phones warranty.

Comment: I'm talking about lock screen clock on Sony D5803

Answer (score 0):

1. First you need to unlock your phones bootloader. You can find the full guide in google.(please search "how to unlock bootloader of " and note that, unlocking bootloader will wipe all your data)
2. Then you need to download a suitable TWRP/Philz custom recovery for your phone. Or you may need to port one yourself.
3. Now flash the new custom recovery to your phone. You can use a flashing tool or adb to flash it.
4. Download SuperSU.zip and flash it via your custom recovery.
5. To check if your phone is successfully rooted, download root checker from play store. And you'll find a new app in your phone named "SuperSU" if your phone is rooted.
6. Now you can use "Gravity Box" or some "Xposed Framework" to change your clock position.

If you don't understand any point, please tell me your phones full model, I'll try to provide you a full details guide.
And Please don't mind my English. I'm not that good at it.